# How do I make Location permission request trigger only when the user clicks on the map tab in a UITabBar?

Tags: xcode, mapkit, core-location

I am building an app using UITabBar and one of the tab items is a map. I only want the user to have to respond to the LocationService() request when they tap on the map tab. However, when the app loads to the tabBar, the location permission request pops up first thing.

[image]

Here is the code for the LocationService()

```
import CoreLocation

protocol LocationServiceDelegate: class {
    func authorizationDenied()
    func setMapRegion(center: CLLocation)
}

class LocationService: NSObject {
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    weak var delegate: LocationServiceDelegate?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    private func checkAuthorizationStatus() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        case .denied:
            delegate?.authorizationDenied()

        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            startUpdatingLocation()

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    private func startUpdatingLocation() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}


extension LocationService: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkAuthorizationStatus()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        if let location = locations.last {
            delegate?.setMapRegion(center: location)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The method was originally called in viewDidLoad so the map would center on the user's location, so I moved it to viewDidAppear, but I still get the same notice when the app launches.

How do I delay the permission request until the user actually taps on the map tab - in this case the DIY Stores tab?

Comment: where and when are you created a reference of LocationService class.

Comment: I originally called it in viewDidLoad for the map tab. I then moved it to viewDidAppear. The results are the same.